# Internet Explorer 8 does not fire AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now, and advices from similar questions have not helped at all. I am attempting to make an AJAX call on $(document).ready in my RoR application, and started off with simple $.get() like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/render_single_stats/<%=@user_params.id%>/');
});
</script>
```

That worked in Opera, Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.
After searching through SO answers, I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timestamp = new Date();
    $.ajax({type : 'POST', url : '/render_single_stats/<%=@user_params.id%>' + '&timestamp=' + timestamp.getTime(), cache : false, contentType : 'application/javascript'});

});
</script>
```

No luck with this call, too.

I am pretty sure jQuery libraries are loaded, as other functions are working. I am using the latest 'jquery-rails' gem.

I also tried to force using IE7 compatibility mode, but no luck.

So after having tried most of advices, am I missing something or doing it wrong?

EDIT:

Turns out problems had to do with my version of jQuery(switched to 1.7.1 from 1.5.2), and then I had to change my html to be valid for IE. Before realising that, I made a step-by-step checks for server response as raw html, then it seemed that jQuery.html() was not working, which led to validations of HTML.

Damn IE :(

So thank you guys for answers, but I can't mark these answers correct, as problem was laying somewhere else.

Comment: You're `get`ting a file, but not doing anything with the result...

Comment: Turn on debugging in Ie and tell us the error you get

Comment: @Kolink the response is RJS template, which does its thing - at least on other browsers

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with IE, and the problem is IE is "catching" the response of the ajax call, so it will execute the ajax call only once then all the other times will use the first original response.
You can test this theory by closing and opening the browser.
the fix is basically tell to IE to NOT catch the response, and you can do that by adding the following headers to your ajax response:

```
response['Cache-Control']='no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
response['Pragma']='no-cache'
response['Expires']='Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT'
```

Comment: The call is not fired even once. I added, however, these headers, but still no luck. They are passed, I checked.

Comment: Isn't this solved by cache:false or simply using getScript(), which by default has cache:false?

Comment: Well, for me even I had cache:false on my ajax call, IE still was catching the call, so I have to specifically tell it on my response headers.
What I will do in your case, if you haven't done it already, is try to see that IE is doing when you try to execute the ajax call. You can install a tool to IE called DebugBar, on there you will be able to see all HTTP(s) calls, responses, headers, and so on, that may give you more clues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving an RJS template, give this a try:

```
$.getScript('/render_single_stats/<%=@user_params.id%>/');
```

According to the jQuery docs,

> [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.
>
> [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) Load a JS file from the server using a GET HTTP request, **then execute it.**